# Connect Spotify(API) token to be allowed to use Spotify Player

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help to connect the authorization token in the URL to be allowed to use the premium only Spotify music player.
I`m using REACT and can't go past this stage, everything is working tree clean I just need to know what to do now.

```
const Login = () => {
  const CLIENT_ID = 'mu client id';
  const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5173';
  const AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
  const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token';
  const SCOPES = 'user-read-private user-read-email';

  const authUrl = `${AUTH_ENDPOINT}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(SCOPES)}`;


  return (
    <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <div className="position-relative">
        <div className="card bg-light p-4 border-0 rounded-3 shadow">
          <div className="card-body text-center">
            <button onClick={handleLogin} className="btn btn-success">
              Login with Spotify
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I expect to be authorized in my other component(Player) to use the music player.
I also have a Home page that contains the musics playlist that is already working and the Player component.
As I said I just need to know how to get the auth from Spotify to use it